# How to fix: Python Error: AttributeError: __enter__?

Tags: python, json, attributeerror, enter

I do a simple code to read the json but i became that error.

```
@bot.slash_command()
async def read(ctx):
    with open("test.json", "r")as f:
        data=json.load(f)
    await ctx.send(data)
```

Error:

> `File "/home/container/main.py", line 51, in open with open("test.json", "r")as f: AttributeError: __enter__`

Comment: You can't pass the alias `f` to `json.load`, you first have to read the file content like this; `f.read()`

Comment: No, `json.loads` takes a string to decode; `json.load` takes a file-like object. (In fact, it's little more than a wrapper around `json.loads(f.read())`. (The error occurs before `json.load` is called anyway.)

Comment: That error indicates you probably redefined `open` at some point.